# `coreclr_create_delegate` doesn't work when called from C++ code on Mac

Tags: c#, c++, macos, .net-core

I need to call method declared in C# library from C++ code on Mac. I am using .Net Core framework 2.0.x (2.0.3, 2.0.4).

To make it work, I call `coreclr_initialize` which runs successfully and returns `0`. I then call `coreclr_create_delegate` by passing required arguments as given below:

```
auto no_del = []( auto x ) { (void)(x); };
auto csharp_runIt = std::unique_ptr<csharp_runIt_t, decltype(no_del)>(nullptr, no_del);

int status = coreclr_create_delegate (
                                          hostHandle,
                                          domainId,
                                          assemblyName.c_str(),
                                          entryPointType.c_str(),
                                          entryPointName.c_str(),
                                          reinterpret_cast<void**>(&csharp_runIt)
                                          );
```

Here,  `hostHandle` and `domainId` are received from `coreclr_initialize`. Rest of the values are: `assemblyName` (dll name), `entryPointType` (class name) and `entryPointName` (function name).
Running it returns negative value with hex code: `0x80070002`.

I am also passing library name, class name and method name as arguments.
As not many have tried it, not much help is available online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I got what was wrong. The .NetCore library was under namespace and thus the `coreclr_create_delegate` was not getting created.
So either don't use namespace or use it while calling in C++ delegate too.

The .Netcore code should be something like:

```
//namespace samplelibrary //This was causing error
//{
    public class SampleClass
    {
        public static string MyFunc()
        {
            return "arrived";
        }
    }
//}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the fully qualified name for that class if it is not in the global namespace. For instance, you need to set `entryPointType` to `samplelibrary.SampleClass` here.